# man – How can I make part of the word italic?

Tags: formatting, manpage, formatted-text, groff

How can I make part of word italic in groff manpage?

When I write this:

```
.TH prog 1
normal
.I italic
```

Output is like this:

> normal *italic*

How can I do this without inserting the space between words `normal` and `italic`?

> normal*italic*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the text between `\fI` and `\fP`:

```
normal\fIitalic\fP
```

Bold is `\fB`.